# Setting base url of the Pact broker

Tags: amazon-ecs, pact, pact-broker

I'm running pact-broker-docker in my ECS. Currently `verificationResultUrl` is pointing to an IP address and so are other URLs of my pact system. I am assuming that is my docker private address. How can I provide base URL to the docker container so that `verificationResultUrl` is resolved to correct URL.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question and provide more detail on your setup: what is a "correct URL" - e.g. a domain name? Is your ECS publicly accessible or only privately accessible? Are you using an ALB/ELB? What is your networking.

Lastly, and most importantly, what are you actually trying to _do_?